# What does SReclaimable in meminfo mean

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Slab memory in /proc/meminfo are split into SReclaimable and SUnreclaim, how can SReclaimable memory get really reclaimed and when?

Answer (score 3):

According [`man proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> **SReclaimable** `%lu` (since Linux 2.6.19)
>
> Part of Slab, that might be reclaimed, such as caches.

It means that SReclaimable is memory that is used by kernel (for example, as a filesystem cache), but should any other need arise, it might be used for other purposes - for example to satisfy memory requests from user applications that cannot be satisfied otherwise, for example by using free (`MemFree`) memory.

Comment: Thanks for the information here! The question I'm still having is I don't see any code in Kernel to really reclaim the S Reclaimable memory...